# Is it safe and a better practice to accept Strings instead of integers or doubles?

Tags: java

Is the second part a good practice in order to avoid user input mismatch?

```
public class StringsAsPrimitiveDate{
Scanner input= new Scanner(System.in);
System.out.println("Please enter your number:");
int numberOne=input.nextInt();
}
```

Or

```
public class StringsAsPrimitiveDate{
Scanner input= new Scanner(System.in);
System.out.println("Please enter your number:");
String numberOne=input.next();
int result = Integer.parseInt(numberOne);   
}
```

Thank you

Comment: If you catch the exceptions Scanner would throw or the exceptions Integer will throw, they both are safe

Comment: The only "particular" issue with using `nextXxx` is you need to remember to consume the dangling new line left in the buffer.  As a "general" recommendation, it might be better to use one `Scanner` to get the user input and use `nextLine` to extract the entire `String`, then use one or more other `Scanner`s to actually parse the text from it - would save a lot of unnecessary questions been posted on SO ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A common problem with `nextInt` is that it leaves behind a new line character which may be accidentally automatically consumed by the next scan. Consider the following code:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

class Main{
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        int rollNo;
        String name;
        Scanner scan=new Scanner(System.in);
        while (true) {
            System.out.print("Enter the roll no of the student: ");
            rollNo=scan.nextInt();
            System.out.print("Enter the name of the student: ");
            name=scan.nextLine();
            System.out.printf("Roll no. %d, Name: %s has been registered%n",rollNo, name);
        }
    }
}
```

**A sample run:**

```
Enter the roll no of the student: 1
Enter the name of the student: Roll no. 1, Name:  has been registered
Enter the roll no of the student: Arvind
Exception in thread "main" java.util.InputMismatchException
    at java.base/java.util.Scanner.throwFor(Scanner.java:939)
    at java.base/java.util.Scanner.next(Scanner.java:1594)
    at java.base/java.util.Scanner.nextInt(Scanner.java:2258)
    at java.base/java.util.Scanner.nextInt(Scanner.java:2212)
    at Main.main(Main.java:10)
```

Note that this problem can occur even with `next` but not with `nextLine` as shown with the following code:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

class Main {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        int rollNo = 0;
        String name;
        boolean valid = true;
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
        while (true) {          
            do {
                System.out.print("Enter the roll no of the student: ");
                try {
                    rollNo = Integer.parseInt(scan.nextLine());
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    System.out.println("The value should be an integer.");
                    valid = false;
                }
            } while (!valid);
            System.out.print("Enter the name of the student: ");
            name = scan.nextLine();
            System.out.println("Roll no. " + rollNo + ", Name: " + name + " has been registered");
        }
    }
}
```

**A sample run:**

```
Enter the roll no of the student: 1
Enter the name of the student: Arvind
Roll no. 1, Name: Arvind has been registered
Enter the roll no of the student: a
The value should be an integer.
Enter the roll no of the student: 12.5
The value should be an integer.
Enter the roll no of the student: 2
Enter the roll no of the student: Avinash
The value should be an integer.
Enter the roll no of the student:
```

**Conclusion:** it is better to use `nextLine` with proper logic (e.g. exception handling, loop back on invalid input etc.) instead of `next` or `nextInt` to avoid issues mentioned above. I also recommend you go through [documentation on Scanner](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html).